# Inequality and bounded functions proof

Tags: inequality

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x,y)$ be two functions.

I would like to prove that

$$\frac{g(x,y)}{f(x)}\geq 0$$

If I want to do so, would it be sufficient if I prove it for the biggest value of $f(x)$?

I mean, let $f(x)\leq M$ for all $x$.

If I prove

$$\frac{g(M,y)}{M}\geq 0$$

would that be sufficient?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Suppose $f(x)=1$ for all $x$. The condition $g(1,y) \geq 0$ for all $y$ does not guarantee that $g(x,y) \geq 0$ for all $x,y$. I will let you write down a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

For this case, the actual max and min of $f$ are less important that its sign (So if $f>0$ that's important, $f> -3$ does not help so much).  Again $f \leqslant -1$ is nice to know if true, as then all you need to do is find when $g(x, y)\leqslant 0$.

In general study when $f(x)$ and $g(x, y)$ share the same sign, if necessary considering different parts of the domains separately.  Which portions of the domains to consider are often given by the zeros of these functions.